# Terilik MVC GRID controls is free of charge?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik-grid, nopcommerce

I am a beginner at using the Terilik grid. I am already working in an nopCommerce project 2.30 ( customization ).

I found **Telerik.Web.Mvc.dll** in the nopCommerce 2.30 project. Please see this image below.

[image]

I have no idea if this control is free of charge or is a trial version. But the Terilik controls work fine in everywhere in my project.

I've tried to set a Column Context Menu in this project ( nopCommerce 2.3), but I can't get `.ColumnContextMenu()` in Razor intellisence in this project.

Please Help me.

Comment: as far as I know you should buy the license, so if you downloaded the dll from somewhere it should be trial.

Comment: there was a free version until 2011, it's no longer free AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.ColumnContextMenu() option get in the nopCommerce 2.65 version of Terilik library.

But i am not sure the Terlirik controls library is free of charge.

Hope will help.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply. But i dont't want to upgrade the 
version of nopCommerce. Can i use the nopCommerce 2.65 terilik dll in 
nopCommerce 2.30 project.

Comment: If you want to ColumnContextMenu option in your existing version of
version of nopCommerce project, please download the Nop 2.65 project and copy the telirik dll in downloded project then refer this dll in your existing project.But i don't know any compatibility problem is occurred. Please make a backup in your existing project. then make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

for the ColumnContextMenu issue, try to using:
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Fluent

maybe you could enjoy Razor intellisence !